# NextWindow 1950 HID Touchscreen isn't working

Tags: drivers, touchscreen

I have HP Touchsmart 300-1220ch and my touch screen doesn't work at all, no event on event tester, but there is a detected and installed.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b14c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd CNF8050 Webcam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 192f:0416 Avago Technologies, Pte. ADNS-5700 Optical Mouse Controller (3-button)
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1934:5168 Feature Integration Technology Inc. (Fintek) F71610A or F71612A Consumer Infrared Receiver/Transceiver
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1926:0006 NextWindow 1950 HID Touchscreen
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo xinput`

Comment: Xinput doesn't show any touchscreen. I can't paste whole output in comment, to much characters.

Comment: Did you tested with `evtest`? May be the _Atmel_ line (idem `xinput`). What's the output of `journalctl -b | grep -i touchscreen` Also would be nice the output of `inxi -SM`.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen):

> If your touchscreen has an USB interface, and it isn't working, then
>   you may need to blacklist the usbtouchscreen driver for it to work:
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe -r usbtouchscreen
> ```
>
> If your touchscreen begins to produce events, then you can permanently
>   blacklist the usbtouchscreen driver:
>
> ```
> echo "blacklist usbtouchscreen" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
> ```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chasedouglas/multitouch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install multitouch-kernel-source
```