# Touchscreen Problem on my laptop after installing ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my Huawei MateBook D Ryzen 5 version.

Everything seems to work fine except for the touchscreen.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Wlcome to [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com). Please be more specific. What is the problem with your touchscreen? What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: I think the touchscreen isn't detected.i can't even find it on the xinput --list output.but it works fine on windows 10 as i dual booted the laptop.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022663/touch-screen-problem)?

Comment: Thanks the touchscreen is now working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Touch screen problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022663/touch-screen-problem)